# decision making statement with string condition

Tags: java, if-statement

What is the correct way to put string in a condition statement?
I tried this, but it won't print x.

```
    String c = "c" ,d = "d";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String selection = in.next();
    if ( c == selection){
        System.out.println("x");
```

Assume I input c.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Java are compared using `str.equals(<string to compare>);`

So in your case it would be `if(c.equals(selection))` not `if(c==selection)`